# How to avoid operating in the IO monad for this whole program?

Tags: haskell, io

I'm writing a Sokoban program in Haskell using the Gloss library, and I'm reaching the point where I'd like to, when the player beats a level, load in a new level from a text file and have the program continue on.

I'm having a little bit of difficulty with this because of Gloss's limitations -- the `play` function to set up a game and have it continuously update looks like this:

```
play    :: forall world
        .  Display                      -- ^ Display mode.
        -> Color                        -- ^ Background color.
        -> Int                          -- ^ Number of simulation steps to take for each second of real time.
        -> world                        -- ^ The initial world.
        -> (world -> Picture)           -- ^ A function to convert the world a picture.
        -> (Event -> world -> world)    -- ^ A function to handle input events.
        -> (Float -> world -> world)    -- ^ A function to step the world one iteration.
                                        --   It is passed the period of time (in seconds) needing to be advanced.
        -> IO ()
```

(Copied directly from http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/1.7.4.1/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-Pure-Game.html)

Here's the `world` type I'm using:

```
data Game = Game
  { levelNumber  :: Int,
    currentLevel :: Level Square,
    won          :: Bool }
```

where `Level`s contain the blocks in the current level. I'm reading in `Game`s using something like this (haven't actually made a generalized one yet, but this is essentially all it would be with a filename argument):

```
startGame = do
  lvl <- readFile "levels/level001.lvl"
  let lvl' = parseLevel lvl
  return $ Game 1 lvl' False
```

So, my difficulty is arising because of the update functions in `play`. I can easily take a `Game` and produce a `Picture` (and a `Game`, etc) without having to read any data in from the file system if I'm just operating on a single level, but since I'm loading levels from files during the middle of the game, I don't know how to avoid making all of my `Game`s `IO Game`s. Maybe this isn't possible in this circumstance, and maybe that's for a good reason? I *will* always be operating on a `Game` pulled from a file but I don't know if it's avoidable at any given point, and if it is, I'd like to avoid it.

Comment: You could use lazy IO ("BOOO! HISSSSS!!!") e.g. with the (my) `directory-tree` package to load a whole directory tree of game files before calling `play`, and pass around the resulting tree type in your `Game`. Or put all your levels in one file and do the same with the standard `readFile`.

Comment: If not, bite it and use the impure [`Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game.playIO`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/latest/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Game.html#v:playIO). You should still be able to keep most of your logic in pure functions.

Comment: Can you show us the parser? Is there no possibility to return eg normal strings?

Comment: @JFritsch I'm using Parsec to parse from a file, so naturally it's going to return an `IO String`.

Comment: Generally, inputs to functions are rarely monadic values; it's usually the output that is monadic or not.

Comment: Either use `playIO` or write your own `playGame` function that only uses `IO` for loading the levels.

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez I ended up using playIO and it's working properly.

Thank you everyone for your help! I wish I could accept one of these answers, haha.

Comment: @BenjaminKovach You can always submit your own answer and accept it!  It's even better if you can show the actual code you used to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using Gloss's `playIO` from [Graphics.Gloss.Interface.IO.Game](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/gloss/1.7.4.1/doc/html/Graphics-Gloss-Interface-IO-Game.html). I needed to change my a couple of my functions to operate on pure data types and output them wrapped in the `IO` monad. Here are the types I had to change:

```
worldToPicture :: World -> IO Picture
eventHandler   :: Event -> World -> IO Picture
stepWorld      :: Float -> World -> IO World
```

For the most part, this only resulted in adding some `return`s to my currently existing functions, but it ended up adding a LOT of functionality (like saving on the fly, loading new levels, using BMP files for graphics, etc). I was also able to keep almost all of my currently existing code free from `IO` since the new functions still took pure data types as parameters. It ended up being a really easy refactor and solved my problem perfectly.